# Access the component name from a Vue directive

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering, hydration

I want to create a custom `Vue` directive that lets me select components on my page which I want to hydrate. In other words, this is what I want to archive

1. I render my `Vue` app on the server (`ssr`)
2. I attach a directive to *some* components, like this:

   ```
   <template>
       <div v-hydrate @click="do-something"> I will be hydrated</div>
   </template>
   ```
3. I send my code to the client and only those components that have the `v-hydrate` property will be hydrated (as `root` elements) on the client.

I want to achieve this roughly this way:

I will create a directives that marks and remembers components:

```
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.directive("hydrate", {
  inserted: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    el.setAttribute("data-hydration-component", vnode.component.name);
  }
});
```

My idea is that in my `inserted` method write a data-attribute to the server-rendered element that I can read out in the client and then hydrate my component with.

Now I have 2 questions:

1. Is that a feasible approach
2. How do I get the component name in `el.setAttribute`? `vnode.component.name` is just dummy code and does not exist this way.

PS: If you want to know why I only want to hydrate parts of my website: It's ads. They mess with the DOM which breaks Vue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could figure it out:

```
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.directive("hydrate", {
  inserted: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    console.log(vnode.context.$options.name); // the component's name
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the name of my single file components using the previously posted solution, so I had a look at the source code of vue devtools that always manages to find the name. Here's how they do it:

```
export function getComponentName (options) {
  const name = options.name || options._componentTag
  if (name) {
    return name
  }
  const file = options.__file // injected by vue-loader
  if (file) {
    return classify(basename(file, '.vue'))
  }
}
```

where `options === $vm.$options`